# MongoDB and Zabbix-agent can't co-exist - libcurl issue

Tags: mongodb, libcurl, zabbix

Whenever I want to set up MongoDB it destroys `zabbix-agent` and then when I fix `zabbix-agent` it destroys `MongoDB`.

I found out that they need different `libcurls` so they remove each others `libcurls` and add their own.

```
root@vm3:~ $ sudo apt-get install -y openssl libcurl3 mongodb-org
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libssl1.1 mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libcurl4 zabbix-agent
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcurl3 mongodb-org mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
```

How can I go around this?

Comment: On 2/3 of my VM where I had Zabbix-agent something bad happened when I tried to install mongodb. on vm1 it destroyed my zabbix-agent and didn't install mongodb while on vm3 it just didn't install mongodb. Vm2 worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile the zabbix_agent with static libraries in order to avoid conflict. Use the repository package for Mongo.

> You may use the --enable-static flag to statically link libraries.

See: [Installation from sources](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/installation/install?s[]=agent&s[]=static&s[]=compile).

Another workaround would be to install Mongo inside a docker container,  depending on application requirements.